# How to export Elasticsearch Index to local

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin, elastica, elasticsearch

How can I export elasticsearch index to my local computer from server and import it to another sever like we do from phpMyadmin for mysql database?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Snapshot API (http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/modules-snapshots.html) or just copy the index directory (which is usualy in your-es-directory/data/your-clustrname/nodes/your-node/your-index) to the target system when the instance is down.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mallocator/Elasticsearch-Exporter can do this without using a shared disk (snapshot functionality requires this).