# Trouble Importing Elasticsearch Index Data Locally

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently facing an issue while attempting to recreate an Elasticsearch database locally from an index backup. Here are the steps I've taken:

I installed Elasticsearch (7.10) locally using the same version that I have running on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). I used the tar distribution for installation.

I downloaded the Elasticsearch index data from a backup source.

I placed all the index files in the Elasticsearch data directory.

Despite following these steps, I'm unable to see the imported data in my local Elasticsearch instance. It appears that Elasticsearch is not recognizing or indexing the data I've placed in the data directory.

I've checked the configuration, permissions, and Elasticsearch logs for any errors, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the issue. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem or can provide guidance on how to troubleshoot this?

I've already tried following this,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29379540/15488129
but the data I'm trying to retrieve were not exported with the snapshot api.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I've also added the question on elastic q/a
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/issue-in-restoring-an-elastic-snapshot/343329